# Invoke-RestMethod display results on multiple lines

Tags: rest, api, powershell

I am quite new to Powershell and API calls.

I am trying to call the BA API from Powershell to return all the Country names where BA are active.

I have got the code returning the result I am after, however all the results return on the single line. I want to display each result on a new line. EG one line per Country.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. My code is below however the API key has been removed.

```
$uri = 'https://api.ba.com/rest-v1/v1/balocations'
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("client-key",'xxxxxxxxxx')

function FlightLocations($uri, $headers)
{
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers 
}

$response = FlightLocations $uri $headers 
Write-Host $response.GetBA_LocationsResponse.Country.CountryName
```

[Powershell Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu523.png)
[API Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gimsr.png)

Comment: Can you include an example of the data you are getting returned?

Comment: Thanks James, 

I have added pictures below the code. For both the powershell results and the raw api data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way Write-Host processes a Array is the issue here, look at this:

Output:

```
$numbers = @('1','2','3','4','5')

DataType Object[] array

Write-Host $numbers does not work
1 2 3 4 5

$numbers | Write-Host works
1
2
3
4
5

Using foreach works to
1
2
3
4
5
```

Code:

```
cls

#test data
$numbers = @('1','2','3','4','5')
"`$numbers = @('1','2','3','4','5')"
#Type of data
"
DataType $($numbers.gettype().Name) $($numbers.gettype().BaseType)"

#Does not work.
"
Write-Host `$numbers does not work"
Write-Host $numbers

#Works
"
`$numbers | Write-Host works"
$numbers | Write-Host


#Another aproach.
"
Using foreach works to"
Foreach ($number in $numbers)
{
    Write-Host $number
}
```